# What does it do when a number is followed by a letter?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, primitive-types

What significance does a letter after a number have? For example the bellow table for [primitive types in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) has letters after the default values of long float and double.

[image: values of primitive data types in Java]

I tested and as far as I can tell they never make a difference. I've also seen things like this in C and C++, for example how the `NULL` macro sometimes expands to `0L`.

Comment: The answer is right in the table.... The letters indicate the type of the particular primitive literal. It makes no difference for a value like `0`, but it matters for literals like `100000000L`

Comment: try `long x = 2147483648;` versus `long x = 2147483648L;` ;-)

Comment: This is all explained on the page that you linked to.  Keep reading past the table itself.

Comment: @om-nom-nom that's all I was waiting for someone to say and no the documentation I linked to doesn't explain it.

Comment: Do you actually need me to copy-paste from the linked page into this one, to show you that it actually _does_ explain it very clearly?

Comment: It definitely does explain it... "An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l; otherwise it is of type int." "A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d." It's not gathered up nicely for you, but reading some more isn't going to kill you...

Comment: Ya well that doesn't explain it. @user3580294 "An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l;" so you're telling me that `long x = 100;` only takes 4 bytes?

Comment: I think given that that page tells you the min/max values of the various primitive types that you can use your brain and/or Google to figure out the rest.

Comment: I guess I accept the rule but don't see why it is, you already specified the type so why add complications by requiring some extraneous character at the end?

Comment: Because you can upcast/promote too. And because sometimes you want to constrain a value (`float` instead of `double`). And because that's the way the compiler is defined to work (in the case of `int`/`long`)

Answer (score 1):

It *does* make a difference.  It just depends on what your values are.

First and foremost, Java will [treat all integral declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) as an `int` unless you specify the `L` (or `l`) suffix.

This means that, while this declaration is invalid:

```
System.out.println(5_000_000_000_000); // too large for an int
```

...this declaration *would* be:

```
System.out.println(5_000_000_000_000L);
```

Java will also [treat all floating-point declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) as a `double` unless you specify `f` or `F`.  You could also specify `d` or `D`, but this is an optional and implied declaration that your literal type is a `double`.

Another example:  while this declaration is *valid* for a `double`:

```
System.out.println(1.17e200);
```

...this one isn't:

```
float f = 1.17e200f; // too large
```

The behavior for other languages (C, C++) would be specific to which standard you're using, but it's not *quite* what you're thinking - a macro is simply a pre-compiler text replace, so wherever the compiler sees `NULL`, it would replace it with `0`.

Comment: So when it says it's an int if the L (or l) isn't specified, what exactly does it mean? It's not as if all of a sudden the type declared as long will no longer reserve 8 bytes of memory. Is it just syntactic sugar?

Comment: @Celeritas I don't get your second sentence, can you rephrase it, please?

Comment: It's not syntactic sugar.  That's simply a hard Java language definition - all numbers without a suffix are simply `int`.

Comment: I'm saying it's kind of stupid. You already declared it as long or float so why need the L or d? Makoto explains that without the L it is treated as an int, but in what sense? It's not as if it allocates the 4 bytes for an int instead of 8 bytes for a long.

Comment: Reconsider both examples (where I'm simply printing things out).  The value isn't actually *stored* anywhere except temporary memory.

Comment: @Celeritas by using `long x = ...` you're saying that left part is long, `L` says that right part is long as well. *without the L it is treated as an int, but in what sense* It will occupy less memory and will have stricter boundaries.